Executing laszip on Ubuntu
I am having trouble getting the laszip program to work on an ubuntu machine, and wondering if I'm missing something obvious.
File downloaded from:
https://laszip.org/
Then I run:
tar -xvzf laszip-src-3.4.3.tar.gz
cd laszip-src-3.4.3
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install

but no exe files are created. There are no files in the bin folder, & I'm at a loss to know what is going on. I need to decompress some laz files for work.

If you want to build the laszip utility, get the full LAStools distribution and follow the build instructions from there:
https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/tree/master
that produced for me a laszip64 executable in the bin64 folder that runs.
I think the laszip-src-* tarballs are only the underlying library code and LAStools provides the command line wrapper.
The binary downloads from https://rapidlasso.de/downloads/ also provide a laszip executable that runs on my Ubuntu if you struggle with the source build.
